# Is there a free and public record of insider trading?

Tags: shares, sec

I am looking for a free and extensive public record of insider trading deals (director dealings).

My understanding is that such data should be public record however I cannot find a decent source. http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Director-dealings has some of what I'm looking for but does not go back far enough, nor does it cite where the data is sourced.

Ideally I would like to access this information from the SEC/FCA respectively rather than relying on a private company trying to make money from selling on the data.

Answer (score 1):

Edgar Online has this information for companies under SEC regulations and they are reported in "Form 4" so that should help guide your search